# How to add items to recyclerview programmatically?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement add to cart functionality using recycler and card views. My catalog is well populated and everything is alright. Or so I think, what I need now is to allow user to add an item to their cart when some button is clicked.

I tried using intents and shared preferences but always one item is passed. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Here is my adapter, the detailsActivity from where one adds items to the cart,the cart activity and the modal I'm using respectively.

Please see my code:

```
public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.myHolder> {
private final List<CartItems> list;
private Context context;

CartAdapter(List<CartItems> list,Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public myHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_list, parent, false);
    return new myHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final myHolder holder,final int position) {
    final CartItems listItem = list.get(position);
    holder.setIsRecyclable(true);
    holder.item_name.setText(listItem.getItem());
    holder.quan.setText(listItem.getQuan());
    holder.cost.setText(listItem.getCost());
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}


static class myHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    final TextView item_name;
    final TextView quan;
    final TextView cost;
    final CardView cardView;
    final ImageView imageView;


    myHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        item_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ph_no);
        quan = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_year);
        cost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.msg);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_image);
    }
}
void addItems(List<CartItems> list,int position){
    CartItems cartItems = new CartItems();
    cartItems.setCost(cartItems.getCost());
    cartItems.setImageId(cartItems.getImageId());
    cartItems.setItem(cartItems.getItem());
    cartItems.setQuan(cartItems.getQuan());
    list.add(position, cartItems);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}}
```

DetailsActivity;

```
public class DetailsActivity extends BaseActivity {
RoundedImageView imageView;
AppCompatTextView textView, textView1, price, quantity, multiplier;
AppCompatImageButton btn_add, btn_sub;
FloatingActionButton fabAdd;
int c = 1;
private RecyclerView rvList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_details);
    init();

    String pathString = String.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra("text"));
    final String image = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
    final String quan = getIntent().getStringExtra("quantity");
    final String pric = getIntent().getStringExtra("price");

    imageView.setBackgroundResource(Integer.parseInt(image));
    textView.setText(pathString);
    quantity.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}{1}", getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.quan_tag), quan));
    price.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}{1}", getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.price_tag), pric));
    btn_sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView1.setText("");
            c--;
            if (c < 1) {
                textView1.setText(String.valueOf(1));
                c = 1;
            } else if (c > 0) {
                textView1.setText(String.valueOf(c));
                String pri = price.getText().toString();
                String Price = pri.replace("ksh", "");
                String Pric = Price.replace("Price:", "");
                String sub = pric.replace("ksh", "");
                price.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}ksh", String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.price_tag) + (Integer.parseInt(Pric) - Integer.parseInt(sub)))));
                multiplier.setText(String.valueOf(c));

            }
        }
    });
    btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView1.setText("");
            c++;
            textView1.setText(String.valueOf(c));
            String Price = pric.replace("ksh", "");
            price.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}ksh", String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.price_tag) + Integer.parseInt(Price) * c)));
            multiplier.setText(String.valueOf(c));
        }
    });
    fabAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String cost = price.getText().toString();
            String quan = quantity.getText().toString();
            String item = textView.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CartActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("item",item);
            intent.putExtra("cost",cost);
            intent.putExtra("quan",quan);
            intent.putExtra("image",image);

            List<CartItems> list = new ArrayList<>();
            CartItems listItem;
            listItem = new CartItems();
            listItem.setItem(item);
            listItem.setQuan(quan);
            listItem.setCost(cost);
            listItem.setImageId(Integer.parseInt(image));
            list.add(listItem);

            CartAdapter listAdapter = new CartAdapter(list,getApplication());
            listAdapter.addItems(list,list.size());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish(); //here add your back function code.
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void init() {
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.item_image);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    btn_add = findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    btn_sub = findViewById(R.id.btn_sub);
    textView1 = findViewById(R.id.tv);
    price = findViewById(R.id.price);
    quantity = findViewById(R.id.quan);
    multiplier = findViewById(R.id.quan_true);
    fabAdd = findViewById(R.id.fab);
}}
```

CartActivity;

```
public class CartActivity extends BaseActivity {
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private RecyclerView rvList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_cart);

    rvList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvList);

    List<CartItems> list = new ArrayList<>();
    CartItems listItem;
    listItem = new CartItems();
    String cost = getIntent().getStringExtra("item");
    String quan = getIntent().getStringExtra("quan");
    String item = getIntent().getStringExtra("cost");
    String image = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");

    listItem.setItem(item);
    listItem.setQuan(quan);
    listItem.setCost(cost);
    listItem.setImageId(Integer.parseInt(image));
    list.add(listItem);

    CartAdapter listAdapter = new CartAdapter(list,getApplicationContext());
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listAdapter.addItems(list,list.size());
    rvList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    rvList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
}}
```

and finally the modal class

```
class CartItems extends ArrayList<String> {

private String Item, Quan, Cost;
private int ImageId;

String getItem() {
    return Item;
}

void setItem(String item) {
    Item = item;
}

String getQuan() {
    return Quan;
}

void setQuan(String quan) {
    Quan = quan;
}

String getCost() {
    return Cost;
}

void setCost(String cost) {
    Cost = cost;
}

int getImageId() {
    return ImageId;
}

void setImageId(int imageId) {
    ImageId = imageId;
}}
```

Comment: @HemantParmar thanks for the link but i guess theres just somthing im not seeing.Can you please look into my code and tell what the problem could be.Ive tried the method suggested in that answer but still outcome is the same